# Catch This Error (Logic/Easy Algebra Error)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$\exists a\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $3a=5$.

Then, $0(3a)=0(5)$. Therefore, $0(a)=0$ and where every $a\in \mathbb{R}$ would satisfy the equation.

What step is wrong in this reasoning?

Comment: What do you mean by $0(3a)$?  Define your notation.

Comment: Multiplication.

Comment: Something is not reversible here.

Comment: So, you know it is is a logic/Easy Algebra Error.  If it's "easy", then I assume you know how to spot such an "easy" error.  So why are  you asking here?

Comment: You are assuming that multiplying by 0 preserves the solutions to the system.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for something logic related as to why multiplying by 0 does not preserve solutions to the system.

Comment: You need to verify that there exists a solution $a$ such that $3a =  5$.  Well, solving for a, we get  $a= \frac 53$. So indeed, a solution exists. Hence it it true that there exists an $a$ such that $3a= 5$. $a = o$ cannot be a solution because $3(0) = 0 \neq 5$.

Answer (score 4):

This problem has nothing to do with $3a$ or $5$.  He or she is saying that if $0 \times a = 0 \times b$, then that implies $a = b$... a clear falsehood since multiplication by $0$ is not a reversible process (as peterwhy pointed out).

Comment: I am not saying that because in your case a=10 and b=4. What do you mean by a reversible process though?

Comment: David: You write "He is saying....".  Who is saying what?  "He?/she?" and to whom are you answering? If you are addressing the OP, then write "you, user....." seem to think  ....." Otherwise you seem to be addressing users other than the OP.

Comment: I was indeed speaking to the other answers/commenters, who downvoted the question and made similar remarks.  He/she... duly noted (and fixed).

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: What do you mean by reversible?

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem is that in order to be completely rigorous you should say the following

$0=0$

Then $0(3a)=0(5)$

Until here everything works.

Now what you need to do is divide by 0 (which is algebraically impossible) and this is why you were wrong.